My NGINX doesn't recognize the backend even tho it's running?
I'm trying to host my website for the first time and NGINX seem like it doesn't recognize my backend.
I tried to make the API location in NGINX to recognize all the APIs and send to port 5000 but doesn't work so I decided to test a single API as above. Their are always an error message in the signup interface but there are nothing in the backend console or any POST/GET log printed out even tho it run perfectly fine in local. Error meaas2024/11/29 10:36:48 [error] 901#901: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.69.121.138, server: avery-insights.icu, request: "POST /auth/signup HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/signup", host: "avery-insights.icu"
    location /auth/signup {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/auth/signup;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

========================================================
Backend code:
server.js:
const authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoutes');
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/table', tableRoutes);

authRoutes.js
router.post('/signup', validateSignup, signup);


The exact error message (especially from nginx logs) would be helpful.

it says:
2024/11/29 10:36:48 [error] 901#901: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.69.121.138, server: avery-insights.icu, request: "POST /auth/signup HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/signup", host: "avery-insights.icu"

Please edit additional information into your question instead of posting them as a comment. The error however indicates that nothing is listening on 127.0.0.1:5000. Either your backend is not running, it's listening on a different port or on the wrong interface. You can verify this for example by running sudo ss -tnlp |grep :5000

I'm sorry for not edit it in the post. The backend is indeed running, I'm running the NGINX and the Backend in an azure VM that remotely controlled by SSH via PuTTY. Well, PuTTY is only providing a single terminal so I opened multiples PuTTY instances at a time connecting to the same VM, each one for a backend (I got 2 backends) and NGINX config. Do you think this might be the issue?

You mention multiple backends. Does that also mean multiple servers?  We sometimes see people who overlook the meaning of localhost  and the IP-addresses for localhost, 127.0.0.1  (IPv4 localhost) and/or ::1 (ip6-localhost)  in their configuration. Using localhost in  the proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/auth/signup directive means that nginx attempts to connect to port 5000 on the same host where nginx is running and not to a different/separate backend server. You'd need to hostname/ip-address of that external server in the nginx config and ensure that on that remote server, the api

is accessible remotely from the nginx instance (and not bound to only the loopback/locahost/127.0.0.1 interface)

The multiple backends are like I have both NodeJs and Flask on my website that handle different functions. And they are connected to the same Azure Vm with the same public IP address and so do the NGINX. I also tried to modify the NGINX and Backend codes to 127.0.0.1 but things seem still doesn't work

We can't help you without seeing actual information. Please edit the output of the ss command into your question.

the error is like the NGINX cannot reach the 127.0.0.1:5000 to the backend. I also tried to change all the localhost to the 127.0.0.1 in the NGINX configs or even the frontend but somehow it didn't work
